# Excel VBA: What is the Maximum Number of String Elements that can be Stored in an Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to build an add-in which would offer the user several more functions.

The basis of these functions is to search through a reasonably large data set of 1424 string elements and return the array element position(s) of each identical match.

I wish to store the data set within the VBA code as it will never change and I do not wish to store it within a spreadsheet. Upon building the array I am faced with a problem whereby on the addition of the 1278th element, the entire array disappears.

Up until the 1277th element the array works and can be interrogated. As soon as I add one more element the entire array disappears! From what I can tell I am nowhere near to the maximum number of array elements allowed in VBA so this is failing due to some other problem.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Function matsearch(ByVal MatSpec As Variant) As String

Dim i As Integer, InstanceCount As Integer, LastInstance As Integer, FirstInstance As Integer
Dim Table_1ASpecList() As String
InstanceCount = 0
LastInstance = 1

Table_1ASpecList = Array("Spec_No", "SA/AS 1548", "SA/AS 1548", "SA/CSA-G40.21", "SA/EN 10028-2", "SA/EN 10028-3", "SA/EN 10028-7", "*****Many More Elements*****")

For i = 0 To UBound(Table_1ASpecList)
    If MatSpec = Table_1ASpecList(i) Then
    InstanceCount = InstanceCount + 1
    LastInstance = i + 1
    End If
Next i
FirstInstance = LastInstance - InstanceCount
matsearch = FirstInstance & " " & InstanceCount
```

Any ideas as to why this is not working?????

Comment: Its been a long time since I did an VBA work, but what happens if you dim your array to the size of 1424? I.e. Dim Table_1ASpecList(1424) As String

Comment: Could this be anything to do with the maximum length of a VBA statement?  "1278" seems a funny number.  If there is a limit for an `Array` method, I would expect the limit to be a multiple of 2. What is the length of the statement?

Comment: @visibleman `myArray = Array(...)` includes an implict `ReDim`.  You cannot size the array in advance nor can you use a static array..

Comment: @Mulldoctor: Why don't you want to store the list in a sheet? If you are developing an add-in then you can just store the list in a sheet in the add-in workbook, which is hidden from users.

Comment: If you create a simple loop that assigns a string to an array for 1500 items, you can see that this is not a limit of the array itself. @TonyDallimore may be right that this is a limit to the length of a line of a single VBA statement.

Comment: @visibleman I tried dim'ing the array but it made not a scrap of difference. Probably something to do with what Tony Dallimore has mentioned.

Comment: @TonyDallimore My suspicions are that it is something to do with the maximum length of a statement although I cannot find any reference to what this would be.
Of my array, I have 1424 individual elements which is 12,985 characters (13,032 characters if spaces are included). These are input over 15 lines with a continuation at the end of each line.
The problem occurs after the addition of the 1278th element which is the 11,670th character (11,716th if spaces included).

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers I would love to store the list in a sheet and refer to it although I have as yet been unable to set this up to work for a function.
I have gotten it to run for an earlier version of what I am trying to do which was a macro ran on a case by case basis which required a re-run each time an input value was changed.
For what I want I would like my values to update live, based on cells referenced within the function.

Comment: You want your values to update live? You said in your question they would never change. So which is it?

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers The function needs to search through a fixed data set, and return the position of elements within this data set which match function inputs which are variable.

So the data set is static, the search criteria changes.

Comment: OK, see the answer I have posted and let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @Mulldoctor , yes, I am afraid I've been away from VBAfor too long. Tony Dalimores answer is absolutely correct on this point.

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers I have amended my code as you have suggested although I still cannot get it to run. If I add a breakpoint to the line of code:

    Table_1ASpecList = Sheet1.Range("MyValues").Value

Comment: ... and look at what value is input into Table_1ASpecList it tells me <Subscript out of range>

I have decared SpecValues as a Range btw

Comment: also, SpecValues = nothing... hmmmm

Comment: I don't see SpecValues anywhere in your code, so don't know what you are referring to.

Comment: Did you enter the values in Sheet1? A1 = Spec_No, A2 = SA/AS 1548 etc.

Comment: Yes, I added the values in to Sheet1 as you suggested and have named the range SpecValues rather than MyValues (sorry, forgot to mention this!!).

    Function matsearch(ByVal MatSpec As Variant) As String

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim InstanceCount As Integer
    Dim LastInstance As Integer
    Dim FirstInstance As Integer
    Dim SpecValues As Range

    Dim Table_1ASpecList() As Variant
    InstanceCount = 0
    LastInstance = 1

    Table_1ASpecList = Sheet1.Range("SpecValues").Value

From here I go into the for loop as written in the original post.

Comment: apologies for not knowing how to enter the text as code within a comment :\

Comment: I've got it to work! At first it wouldn't enter the For Loop and I managed to get it to do this by removing the     .Value expression from Table_1ASpecList = Sheet1.Range("SpecValues").Value. I have since tagged it back on and the code works. After this change I was still getting a <Subscript out of Range> error so after trying many things I changed the Array expression from Table_1ASpecList(i) to Table_1ASpecList(i, 1), essentially adding a further dimension to it and now it works. Thanks to all for the help especially @ExcelDevelopers :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Visual Basic Editor, change the IsAddIn property of ThisWorkbook to False. Activate the workbook and enter the values to be populated in Table_1ASpecList into a sheet. Give the range a name, say "MyValues". Change the IsAddIn property back to True, and then amend your code to:

```
Dim Table_1ASpecList() As Variant
Table_1ASpecList = Sheet1.Range("MyValues").Value
```